# How can I make Craft's caching aware of fields used inside a plugin?

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-neo

I have a complex template which uses various modules and sub-components for which I opted for handling all the logic and rendering directly in PHP, as it felt like it was too complex a job for twig.

Currently, when I change a field (e.g. swap out an image) inside one of the modules, the surrounding cache isn't busted, so the site doesn't update.

My question is: How can I make Craft aware of fields used inside a plugin within a `{% cache %}` tag, so that when a field is changed, the surrounding cache is busted?

I am aware of the [TemplateCacheService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService), but unsure if / how I can use that in this case (I had a bit of an experiment with no success).

The `modules` represent a Neo field, but my assumption is that this would work very similarly if not identically to if this was a matrix field.

A super-reduced test case looks something like the following:

```
{% for module in modules %}
    {% cache using key module.id %}
        {{ craft.control.renderModule(module) }}
    {% endcache %}
{% endfor %}
```

*_modules.twig*

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class ControlVariable
{

    public function renderModule($module)
    {
        return craft()->control_modules->renderModule($module);
    }
}
```

*ControlVariable.php*

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class Control_ModulesService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{

public function __construct()
{}

public function renderModule($module)
{
    ?>

    <!-- How can Craft know when this image changes? -->
    <img src="<?= $module->myImageField->first()->getUrl(); ?>">

    <?php
}
```

*Control_ModulesService.php*

FWIW, in the following setup, the cache is successfully busted when changing the image field in the CMS:

```
{% for module in modules %}
    {% cache using key module.id %}
        <img src="{{ module.myImageField.first().getUrl() }}">      
    {% endcache %}
{% endfor %}
```

*_modules.twig*

Answer (score 1):

The `{% cache %}` tag tracks [Elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) (Users, Entries, Categories, Tags, etc.), so if you're want to do this using a plugin, then the plugin's field type needs to inherit from [BaseElementFieldType](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType) and needs to implement its own element type.

From there, it's just a matter of calling [`craft()->templateCache->includeElementInTemplateCaches()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService#includeElementInTemplateCaches-detail).

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me Brad! If I could just clarify / confirm something: the field types I am outputting the values of in the plugin are actually native Craft fields (e.g. `myImageField` above is just a regular assets field). Would that change anything?